# How Can I Get last Inserted ID In SIGN UP Page In Membermouse Plugin?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

When I Register For Free SIGNUP on Membermouse,Data is Entered into wordpress table and membermouse table .

My question:

How can we get last inserted ID from wordpress user table  in membermouse free sign up page .???

or

How can we copy last member details inserted into wordpress user table to my own table (with PHP or MYSQL queries automatically).??

Database screenshots:

Wordpress Table(entries with membermouse)
[image]
My Table
[image]

Code :

My custom sign up code doesn't work under $req=$orderRequest->submitRequest();,so i put above PLUGIN code as you can see in code. .i also know both queries are working on same time,thats why i'm unable to get lastinserted id .

```
<?php 
//my custom sign up code to insert entry into my own table.
 require_once('../../../../wp-config.php'); 
$email=$_POST['email'] ;   
$pass=$_POST['password'];     
global  $wpdb;  

 $randomFact = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM lwy_users where user_email='".$email."'");
$memid=$randomFact[0]->ID;  //this  $memid is null ..i want value of  $memid

   if( email_exists( $email )) 
  {  

   }                   
   else    

   {           

$wpdb->query("insert into mm_members (MemberID,MemberUserEmail ,MemberPassword,MemberClass) VALUES ('".$memid."','".$email."','".$pass."','B') "  );

   }  
//membermouse sign up code
require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");
require_once("../includes/mm-constants.php");
require_once("../includes/init.php");



$orderRequest = new MM_FreeMemberWebformRequest($_POST);
$req=$orderRequest->submitRequest();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your IDs are auto-incrementing, so I'm assuming the highest numbered ID is the most recently inserted. This query would return the email that was most recently inserted.

```
select user_login from lwy_users 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM lwy_users) 
group by user_login;
```

[Here's a sqlfiddle demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5aa4/7)

Comment: both queries are working on same time,so how can i  do  this??

Comment: They aren't in fact at the same time, you do one and then the other. You should save the results from this query the way you do with that `$randomFact` variable, and insert into the my_table.

Comment: i try with this query ,doesn't work.check is this right?  SELECT lwy_users.ID FROM table lwy_users WHERE lwy_users.ID = lwy_users.MAX(ID)

Comment: Here you go, had to mess with it for a while, see edit. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5aa4/7

Comment: @ J-Dizzle.i have deleted some members from lwy_users.when i insert new member .entries goes in between .so,here max(ID) doesn't work.

Comment: select * from lwy_users  WHERE ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM lwy_users) group by $email .i tried this also.But $email is doesn't enter in lwy_users...

Comment: I'd suggest a datestamp then, a column for Created_On (with default value @ current time-- google sql default value datetime), then use the same MAX query, it works on date. use this SQL fiddle